# Attempting to Deploy a clickhouse stack to docker swarm and getting error: Service Builder failed to build: COPY failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, clickhouse

Im the process of learning docker swarm, I have a three node nuc setup running docker swarm at the moment on Ubuntu 16.04. I am looking to build a 2 node clickhouse cluster using the official image from:

https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/dockerfile

I can run this easily as an image on one node but I am trying to deploy the docker image to 2 of the nodes so I can build the cluster from there using this documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

But I am getting the following error when I run  `docker-compose up -d`:

```
ERROR: Service 'builder' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder795701575/docker_related_config.xml: no such file or directory
```

directory map:

```
my_app
----docker-compose.yml
----docker
-------client
-------server
-------builder
            --Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:
https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG repository="deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/stable/ main/"
ARG version=19.1.13
ARG gosu_ver=1.10

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        dirmngr \
        gnupg \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E0C56BD4 \
    && echo $repository > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
        apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated --yes --no-install-recommends \
            clickhouse-common-static=$version \
            clickhouse-client=$version \
            clickhouse-server=$version \
            libgcc-7-dev \
            locales \
            tzdata \
            wget \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /var/cache/debconf \
        /tmp/* \
    && apt-get clean

ADD https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-amd64 /bin/gosu

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY docker_related_config.xml /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x \
    /entrypoint.sh \
    /bin/gosu

EXPOSE 9000 8123 9009
VOLUME /var/lib/clickhouse

ENV CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  builder:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-builder
    build: docker/builder
  client:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-client
    build: docker/client
    command: ['--host', 'server']
  server:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    build: docker/server
    ports:
      - 8123:8123
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly? help is appreciated.

**Update:**

Attempted comment solution but did not work:

```
ERROR: Service 'builder' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder511288209/docker_related_config.xml: no such file or directory
```

Comment: didn't seem to work

Comment: is the file in the same folder as your dockerfile ?

Comment: Edited my directory map. I had made a mistake. Which file are you referring to?

Comment: the file `docker_related_config.xml` should be in the same folder as `dockerfile` or you should supply the relativ path to `COPY` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Github repository for this project and try to build it from there: https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/tree/master/docker/server

Don't just copy the Dockerfile, but clone the project and build it from there.

Comment: thank you, with the combination of this and what LinPY was mentioning I got it running.